# Create user and sign in automatically with Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

On the login page of my web app I have added a link for creating a new user. I would like the user to fill up the form (first name, last name, email, password), create the new user on the server AND to sign the new user in automatically, without any need of redirecting him to the login page again. Additionally, I would like the user to land on a specific page (say, a list of orders).

Is it feasible, and if so, how to do it properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After saving a user to the db, you can log them in programatically, like so:

```
Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, authorities);
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

Then just send a redirect.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm (though I've used PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken istead).